# Login with Ajax in Codeigniter (Controllers and Models can not execute Query Database)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a View that will send Login data with Ajax jquery as follows :
views/Login.php

```js
I have a View that will send Login data with Ajax jquery as follows :
views/login.php

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

That will send username & password to Model Login / insert_login
controller/Login.php

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct ()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Login_Model');
  }

  public function index ()
  {
    $this->load->view('Login');
  }

  public function insert_login ()
  {
    $user = $this->input->post('user');
    $pass = $this->input->post('pass');

    $cekUser = $this->Login_Model->check_user($user);

    if (empty($cekUser->username)) {
      $sts = 'user_wrong';
    }else{
      if (md5($pass) != $cekUser->password) {
        $sts = 'pass_wrong';
      }else{
        if ($cekUser->tipe_user == 'admin'){
          $sts = 'success_admin';
          $this->session->set_userdata(array('user'=>$user,'status'=>'admin'));
          redirect(base_url('Admin/Home'));
        }else{
          $sts = 'success_user';
          $this->session->set_userdata(array('user'=>$user,'status'=>'user'));
          redirect(base_url('Admin/Home'));
        }
      } 
    }

    echo '{"status":"'.$user.'"}';  
  }
 
  public function logout ()
  {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url('Admin/Login'));
  }

}
?>

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_Model extends CI_Model {

  public function check_user ($user)
  {
   return $this->db->get_where('m_user', array('username' => $user))->row();
  }

}
?>
```

I wonder why Query Database Function get_where / query / Any query can not be executed, but I have added Liblary Database in autoload.php:
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session'), 
And I test using a Controller other than Login Controller still can run.
Why only in the model & Login controller can not execute Query?

But if I try to display the data captured divariabel:

```html
    $user = $this->input->post('user');
    $pass = $this->input->post('pass');
    echo $user.' '.pass;
```

When i test like it can already get and display data, tapi masalahnya kenapa ketika memunculkan Query tidak muncul apapun. 
Please help me, I've really stack, stay up every day to clean up my job ...

Comment: what is appear when you print_r($user.' '.pass); you can see the fields ?

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Answer (score 0):

set data into array in controller file

set name of array key as your database field name `username` & `password`

controller file

```
  $user = $this->input->post('user');
  $pass = $this->input->post('pass');
  $where=array('username'=>$user,
            'password'=>md5($pass));
  $cekUser = $this->Login_Model->check_user($where);
```

give yout table name in `from` query

model file

```
class Login_Model extends CI_Model {

  public function check_user ($where)
  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table_name');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $res=$this->db->get();
    return $res->result();
  }

}
```

Comment: I just need to check the username only in the array, I've followed your suggestion, but echo '{"status": "'. $ User. '"}'; Does not show anything.

Comment: my controller :

public function insert_login ()
{
  $user = $this->input->post('user');
  $pass = $this->input->post('pass');

  $where = array('username'=>$user);
  
  $cekUser = $this->Login_Model->check_user($where);

  if (empty($cekUser->username)) {
    $sts = 'user_wrong';
  }else{
    if (md5($pass) != $cekUser->password) {
      $sts = 'pass_wrong';
    }else{
      if ($cekUser->tipe_user == 'admin'){
        $sts = 'success_admin';
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('user'=>$user,'status'=>'admin'));
      }
    } 
  }

Comment: My model :

Public function check_user ($where)
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('m_user');
  $this->db->where($where);
  $res = $this->db->get();
  return $res->row(); // i need row result
}
}

Comment: so in array pass only username like  `$where=array('username'=>$user);` and in model class return  `return $res->row();`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, sorry, I was wrong configuration database, so my data does not appear.